# Union of multiple overlapping sets efficiently?

Tags: time-complexity, sets

I have $n$ sets, each of which overlaps heavily with the other sets, and I want the union of all of them. The obvious solution is to take the union of each set, one by one, which results in $O(n^2)$ running time, but is there a better solution?

**Clarification from the comments:** Assuming all sets have $n$ elements, so $n$ represents both the number of sets and the size of each set.

Comment: Why do you conclude that approach takes $O(n^2)$ running time?  Are you assuming all sets have $n$ elements, so $n$ represents both the number of sets and the size of each set?

Comment: If you have $n$ sets, each with $n$ elements, you need to read $n^2$ elements.

Comment: Are you looking for practical or theoretical results? If you have few elements, you can use things like bitwise operations to have the CPU do stuff faster.

Comment: @D.W. Yes, sorry, I forgot to specify that.

Comment: @PålGD I am looking for practical results -- I know that theoretically, I will have to go through all the elements.

Comment: If you're looking for practical results you have to state expected number of unique elements, number of sets, type of elements, are they numbers, if so, in which range?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer to your question depends heavily on the representation of the sets. For simplicity, I am assuming that we have $n$ sets of integers, where all the integers are between $0$ and $n-1$ (conforming to your statement that the $n$ sets each have up to $n$ elements).

- If the sets are represented in **a generic set data structure such as a hash table,** as pointed out in the comments, that means even *reading* the input takes $\Omega(n^2)$ time in the worst case. This implies that it is completely impossible to avoid the $n^2$ algorithm of unioning all the sets together.
- One common compact representation of sets for practical results is using **bit-vectors.** If the length of a machine integer is 8 bytes (64 bits), then we represent a set of up to $n$ elements using a bit-vector of length $n$ which is represented as an array of $\frac{n}{64}$ integers. As bitwise xor is an $O(1)$ hardware operation, unioning two of these sets only takes $\frac{n}{64}$ time, and doing this $n$ times we have $O(\frac{n^2}{64})$ for the whole union. Still quadratic, but much better in practice.
- There are other interesting representations of sets. One representation is using **logical predicates:** a set here is a formula $\varphi(n)$ which is true exactly when $n$ is in the set.
  For example, the set of all integers between $1$ and $10000$ would be represented as the predicate "$1 < n < 10000$" (expressed as a syntax tree).
  Unioning this kind of predicate together *can* be much faster than unioning the sets, if the sets are of a simple structure, like ranges ("$1 < n < 10000$"), unions of a few different cases ("$n < 5 \text{ or } n = 10$"), or specific elements ("$n = 5$"). When unioning, we apply simplifications to the resulting predicates (e.g., "$x \text{ or  } x$" simplifies to "$x$").
- Finally, extending this, one way of representing predicates that happens to be especially effective is using a **[binary decision diagram](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_decision_diagram),** which is kind of like a [decision tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decision_tree). These structures lead to a pretty compact encoding of common sets like ranges and predicates. They can be unioned together efficiently in $O(m)$ where $m$ is the size of the BDD structure, so the total time will be $O(m \cdot n)$. For both this and the formula representation, there is a necessary assumption that the sets we are unioning together are "not too complex" and have a more compact representation than just listing out the elements. But, even in the worst case, it only takes $O(n \log n)$ space to store a set of $n$ elements explicitly as a BDD, so we aren't paying much of a cost, and in practice, the sets will often overlap significantly and we will get a more compact representation.